# Delicatessen, alias « deli » : comment le traduire en français ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, allemand

Le fameux « deli », pour delicatessen, dans le contexte new-yorkais d'un "deli" qui livre des café-bagels aux particuliers habitants le quartier. Si l'on traduit deli par déli, on part du principe qu'en français ce terme peut être forgé et compris d'un lecteur francophone, ce dont je doute fort, sauf s'il est "New York-savvy". En français rien d'équivalent :

- cafét' : non
- traiteur : non
- épicerie : très bof

Answer (score 6):

Selon le cas (et l'[endroit](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delicatessen_%28gastronomie%29)), on parle essentiellement d'une *épicerie fine* ([Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/delicatessen/574678), [GDT](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26529326), [Termium](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=DELICATESSEN&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs)), d'une *charcuterie* ou d'*aliments fins* pour le type de produit, par exemple. On a des emplois spécialisés comme : l'[*assiette de charcuterie*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=2497431) pour *delicatessen platter* ; le [*charcutier-traiteur*](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8870623) pour le *delicatessen dealer* (GDT) ; le [*comptoir déli*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=DELICATESSEN%20COUNTER&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) pour *delicatessen counter* (Termium). Si le sens permettait la préparation de plats comme tels, ce pourrait être un type de [*traiteur*](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=traiteur&francetermeSearchDomaine=0&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search) ([TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/traiteur), [Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/traiteur/78983?q=traiteur#78031)) ou de [restaurateur](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/restaurateur), selon le cas, à défaut d'être un restaurant (en contexte nord-américain). Le *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* (dir. A. Rey, ed. *Le Robert*) parle du germanisme *delikatessen*, dont on dit qu'il fut précédé du calque *délicatesses* chez [Gaston Leroux](https://books.google.com/books?id=nSIxBgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT3745&dq=inauthor%3A%22Gaston%20Leroux%22%20delikatessen&pg=PT3737#v=onepage&q=delikatessen&f=false) en 1920, pour les *produits alimentaires de luxe et la boutique qui les vend*. Le *TLFi* note un sens pour des *mets, généralement sucrés, fins et délectables*, par exemple chez [André Gide](https://books.google.com/books?id=K7HvAAAAMAAJ&q=inauthor:%22Andr%C3%A9%20Gide%22%20%22Plateau%20charg%C3%A9%20de%20d%C3%A9licatesses%20et%20de%20fruits%22&dq=inauthor:%22Andr%C3%A9%20Gide%22%20%22Plateau%20charg%C3%A9%20de%20d%C3%A9licatesses%20et%20de%20fruits%22&hl=en) (« plateau chargé de délicatesses et de fruits [...] »). Le [FEW](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/179729) réfère [indirectement](https://books.google.com/books?id=lXY_8pyDPIQC&q=inauthor:%22Kristoffer%20Nyrop%22%20d%C3%A9licatesses&dq=inauthor:%22Kristoffer%20Nyrop%22%20d%C3%A9licatesses&hl=en) à un exemple chez Molière (*L'Avare*, [II, sc. VI](https://books.google.com/books?id=1NpbAAAAcAAJ&dq=moli%C3%A8re%20%22ni%20les%20autres%20d%C3%A9licatesses%20qu'il%20faudrait%22&pg=PA208#v=onepage&q=moli%C3%A8re%20%22ni%20les%20autres%20d%C3%A9licatesses%20qu'il%20faudrait%22&f=false) : « C'est une fille accoutumée à vivre de salade, de lait, de fromage et de pommes, et à laquelle, par conséquent, il ne faudra ni table bien servie, ni consommés exquis, ni orges mondés perpétuels, ni les autres délicatesses qu'il faudrait pour une autre femme ; [...] » ) qu'on lirait dans ce sens. On sait que le mot anglais *delicatessen* est un [emprunt](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=delicatessen) à l'allemand d'un emprunt au français...

---

*(Marchand de) délicatesses* serait délicieux si on cherchait vraiment un calque, comme l'auteur Leroux. Autrement on a plusieurs possibilités, même au besoin les *aliments de choix* et *produits alimentaires de luxe*, et en combinaison, avec la boutique, l'épicerie, marchand qui les vend etc. si l'*épicerie fine* ne fait l'affaire. Dans d'autres cas on aura le restaurateur ou généralement un *lieu de restauration* à saveur particulière. On pourrait aussi employer le mot allemand *delikatessen* comme tel (ou même le *deli*, ou *déli* avec l'accent, comme dans ce *comptoir* canadien) si on veut l'emprunt. On peut semble-t-il exprimer avec précision ce dont il s'agit selon le contexte, avec des références aux métiers et commerces traditionnels, ou à la nature des produits, rendant le besoin d'une traduction plus précise surtout théorique, à mon avis.

Comment: Malheureusement, je connais tous ces aspects de contexte, étymologie et variantes mais aucune ne fonctionne dans le contexte d'un café-bagel qu'on se fait livrer dans son appartement de New York par le bar/deli du coin. Traiteur évoque plus les "plats cuisinés" à la franco-française version plus chic, et les acceptations Termium sont presque toujours des canadismes impraticables en français.

Comment: En France, le concept n'existe pas effectivement, il y a des "spécialistes" (traiteurs, épicerie fine, viennoiseries, chocolats, ...)

Comment: Succincte, et  non paresseuse… Cette livraison de café-bagel ne fonctionne pas car il précise qu'il se fait livrer un café-bagel par le deli du coin.

Comment: "Livraison de café-bagel" n'est pas un nom, c'est une définition de service. Votre réponse péremptoire inclut le terme déli (francisé), partant donc du principe que le terme est recevable tel quel en français, présupposé qui en soi pose question (question qu'évoquait mon premier post tant décrié, certes en termes succincts mais clairs). Les mots-valises du type déli-vraison ne sont d'aucune aide, puisque nous ne sommes pas dans un univers francophone, mais new-yorkais. Les textes qui traduisent Tesco par Supérette me font toujours sourire… ou lever les yeux au ciel, selon l'humeur.

Comment: Je ne cherche pas à m'adresser à un public anglophone et n'ai jamais rien signifié de tel. Je cherche une traduction qui respecte le contexte social source — et qui évite les inepties du genre "Joe Walsh se rendit à la Supérette". Si l'on traduit deli par déli, on part du principe qu'en français ce terme peut être forgé et compris d'un lecteur francophone, ce dont je doute fort, sauf s'il est "New York-savvy".